# Debian: Apache User www-data is not able to write under /dev/shm/mydirectory for writing

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg, apache-http-server

I am executing ffmpeg from a php script using shell_exec(). As it does not work, I have changed /etc/passwd temporarily to allow to login with Apache user (www-data). If I run the command, it shows this error:

```
[dash @ 0x563dc823b040] Opening '/dev/shm/mpeg-dash/init-stream0.m4s' for writing
```

and:

```
[dash @ 0x563dc823b040] Opening '/dev/shm/mpeg-dash/.tmp' for writing
```

Please, find all the output shown in the console here:

```
www-data@joaquin2:/dev/shm$ ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:password@172.25.1.41:21102 -an -c:v copy -b:v 2000k -f dash -window_size 4 -extra_window_size 0 -min_seg_duration 2000000 -remove_at_exit 1 /dev/shm/mpeg-dash/
ffmpeg version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 1 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 2 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 3 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 1 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 2 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 1 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 3 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 9 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 2 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 6 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 7 packets
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x563dc81f8100] RTP: missed 7 packets
[h264 @ 0x563dc81fb420] out of range intra chroma pred mode
[h264 @ 0x563dc81fb420] error while decoding MB 128 28
[h264 @ 0x563dc81fb420] concealing 27313 DC, 27313 AC, 27313 MV errors in I frame
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:password@172.25.1.41:21102':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.240000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 4096x2160, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
[dash @ 0x563dc823b040] Opening '/dev/shm/mpeg-dash/init-stream0.m4s' for writing
Output #0, dash, to '/dev/shm/mpeg-dash/':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 4096x2160, q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[dash @ 0x563dc823b040] Opening '/dev/shm/mpeg-dash/.tmp' for writing
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Not a directory
Error writing trailer of /dev/shm/mpeg-dash/: Not a directoryframe=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.232x    
video:275kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

I am using the "/dev/shm/mpeg-dash" folder because it is recommended for overwrite files each 2 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: you can `sudo su - www-data` to log in as a specific user, without need to change password

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't understand your response. I am able to log in, but the user www-data cannot write to /dev/shm/mpeg-dash althought www-data is the owner of the folder.

Comment: It was just a comment how to log in better in www-data, it was not an answer. Unix&Linux sister site is probably better for such question, but whi recommended to use /dev/shm? Maybe you skipped the setup part (and probably who wrote the guide had no idea [or s/he should have written the reasoning]. shm is for shared memory. If you are not sharing it, do not use it. If it is just to overwrite files, use /tmp (which since ages it use tmpfs, so nothing is written to disk).